# Linked servers connection and security issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to implement Linked Servers. but I am having problems establishing connection to my two servers, **SRV-AXDEV** and **SRV-APP1**

I have already created the linked server SRV-AXDEV under SRV-APP1 with the following configurations:

> Linked Server: SRV-AXDEV
>
> Server Type:SQL Server
>
> Security: be made using this security context (with the log in
>   credentials i used when i connect to SRV-AXDEV)
>
> collation compatible: False
>
> Data Access: True
>
> RPC: True
>
> RPC Out: True
>
> Use Remote Collation: True
>
> Collation Name:
>
> Connection Time out: 0
>
> Query Time out:  0
>
> Distributor:  False
>
> Publisher : False
>
> Subscriber:  False
>
> Lazy Schema Violation: False
>
> Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions: True

This is the list of my databases in SRV-AXDEV:

[image 4](http://i1159.photobucket.com/albums/p631/enjei26/05_zpsfdb97045.png)

But when I try to run this query:

```
Select * from [SRV-AXDEV].[GFII_AX2009_DB_LIVE].[dbo].[InventTable]
```

I keep on getting this error:

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10"
>   for linked server "SRV-AXDEV" does not contain the table
>   ""GFII_AX2009_DB_LIVE"."dbo"."InventTable"". The table either does not
>   exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

I hope you could help me with this problem.

Comment: Are you sure the schema is "dbo"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties which have been declared are perfect.
Check the following steps

1. Check wether the table exists on the perticular linked server database.
2. Check the schema of the table as "DBO"
3. check the security login for linked server wether the user having the required permission for access the table(better to login with SA)